# Difficulty Exposing Janus UDP Ports on AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, port, docker-swarm

I've created a stack definition in Docker Compose format and used the AWS CLI to transpile it into a CloudFormation template (YAML). All my web services seem to be working fine, except I'm having difficulty exposing the RTP-ports that Janus WebRTC server uses. I restricted my Janus ports to 20000-20500 and added that to my docker-compose. However, when the AWS CLI transpiles my compose file into a CloudFormation template, it creates a set of resources such as a load balancer entry, security group, etc. for every single port. This is problematic because I can only create 500 resources.

I'm seeking advice on how to properly expose my Janus UDP ports in my AWS CloudFormation template. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
version: "3.9"

services:
.
.
.
  janus:
    image: myECR/Janus
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
     ports:
      - 80:80
      - 7088:7088 
      - 8088:8088 
      - 8188:8188
      - 20000-20500:20000-20500/udp
    deploy:
      replicas: 2

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Kaan.

I was expecting that the AWS cli would create a more understandable and readable port mapping for large ranges. The output template is not deployable due to its big size.